# Elasticsearch-py date malformed

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to index some data but I keep getting the error

```
error: reason: failed to parse [date] type: mapper_parsing_exception, caused_by: Invalid format: 2016-08-12\t17:35:26 is malformed at \t17:35:26
```

My mapping looks like

```
'date': { 'type': 'date', 'format': 'dateOptionalTime' },
```

Is there a different way to create the date mapping?

EDIT: Here is a line from the document.  I can get it to index just fine when I set time to string and date to date but the date shows a bogus time attached to it.  So it looks like ES is taking my date (2016/9/20) and adding a time to it.  In my case it adds 19:00:00.  Which is why I can't figure out why it doesnt like the time.

```
2016-06-14  18:12:35    1.1.1.1 GET /origin-www.origin.com/Images/pipe-gray.png?    200 1442    0   "http://www.origin.com/Main.css"    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36" "__qca=P0-920525163; s_fid=4CDFF16906A35CC4; __CSCookie=z5ayStQYdIbcPTxGKyhsjRIi0peP5GAP6K; icxid=1459286804904; icxid=1459286804904; ASP.NET_SessionId=dzg3esjzp4tpg; __SessionCookie=gXA9BuDiF245ZJeuh; dtCookie=0C05828501CE759D; s_vi=[CS]v1|2A069D04051D2E2A; __CSUserIbcIDCookie=NL7VeN+rh05z5FWSCgTnzTC6G;"
```

Comment: Can you post the original document you are trying to index? Your date should be in this format "2016-08-12T17:35:26"

Comment: added to question

Comment: So I thought I fixed it by adding                 'date': { 'type': 'date', 'format': "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||ISO8601||yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" },
But all this did was create the date as a string

Comment: Are you using Logstash to parse your log files and index into ES? If thats the case you should check how logstash is parsing your log lines. Also check the ES log files while you index and see if you see any errors or warnings while indexing.

Comment: I am using Python to do the parsing.  When I print my hash table the date shows up as 2016-02-10\t10:25:30 which should match my format.  The has table is fed to a json dump and when I step through I see date = the same as the hash table print.

Comment: Before u add the date to hashtable or before u feed it to json, can you not convert this date "2016-02-10\t10:25:30" to this "2016-02-10T10:25:30" If you give elasticsearch this format, you should be able to use the original mapping - dateOptionalTime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123809/discussion-between-jay-and-maltman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding the date to hashtable or before u feed it to json, convert the date "2016-02-10\t10:25:30" to this "2016-02-10T10:25:30"

If you give elasticsearch this format, you should be able to use the original mapping - dateOptionalTime.